# Import Remote CSV with Magmi getting Error

Tags: magento, csv, import, magento-1.7, magmi

I tried several times to import a remote CSV file from the supplier with Magmi. If I download the CSV file and open it with OpenOffice and save it again with  Duoble Quotes, than it works fine. Seems that the supplier provides me an Excel (saved with Mixcrosoft Excel). Any idea how I can configure this in the right way in Magmi, so it will be processed in the right way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under the **Configure Profile > Datasources** section in Magmi, you will find a section labeled **CSV options**.

By default, the following values are:

**CSV separator:** `,`
**CSV Enclosure:** `"`

You can simply change these to match the formatting of your CSV.  In your case, their are no double quote enclosures, so you can leave the **CSV Enclosure** field blank and update your profile.

Keep in mind though that descriptions containing commas `,` may cause header/column mismatch errors.  Make sure you're escaping these correctly for Magmi to process.

Comment: I have something like this:
"sku","name","content","sku_supplier","stock","qty","color"
"15424","product1","new description","23435","345","1","blue,white"

I leave all fields in Datascource (seperator en enclosure blank). Also tried other ways (it adds the \ after saving). But still not reading the CSV file in right way. Need some hardcode in file? Or is the another solution for this one

Comment: Have you read the [Magmi Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_new_products)?  You are missing some mandatory columns.  You need to include **"attribute_set","type","sku"**.  If you can't modify the CSV every time, you can simply use the **Default Values setter** plugin from within Magmi, and add the missing required columns and their values.  For example, you can use `Default` for **attribute_set** and `simple` for **type**.

Comment: I did all these things. I am not that new to Magmi. Already did a lot of local importing to Magento. Seems that the handeling of the duible quote and comma is not working well. Also when I use Import Limiter and just focus on the essential columns, it still not working.

Comment: Be sure to escape double quotes in values with a second double quote, e.g. `"mysku","name with ""quotes"" in it"`